# Return values of array if in_array() returns true

Tags: php, arrays

I have one multi dimensinal array,

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [item_no] => 1.01
            [sor_id] => 2
            [selected_qty] => 7
            [price] => 3
            [type] => S
            [form_name] => GSOR
            [parent_id] => 89
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [item_no] => 1.03.03
            [sor_id] => 7
            [selected_qty] => 1
            [price] => 50
            [type] => S
            [form_name] => GSOR
            [parent_id] => 89
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [item_no] => 1.23
            [sor_id] => 28
            [selected_qty] => 6
            [price] => 60
            [type] => S
            [form_name] => GSOR
            [parent_id] => 89
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [item_no] => 6.03
            [sor_id] => 64
            [selected_qty] => 1
            [price] => 50
            [type] => S
            [form_name] => GSOR
            [parent_id] => 61
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [item_no] => 4.02
            [sor_id] => 42
            [selected_qty] => 1
            [price] => 39
            [type] => S
            [form_name] => GSOR
            [parent_id] => 40
        )

)
```

I have one recursive function which returns true if the value is exist in multi dimensional array other,

Recursive in_array() function,

```
function in_array_r($needle, $haystack, $strict = false) {
    foreach ($haystack as $item) {
        if (($strict ? $item === $needle : $item == $needle) || (is_array($item) && in_array_r($needle, $item, $strict))) {
            return true;
            // return $haystack;
            // print_r($haystack);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Example,

```
 echo $item_2 = in_array_r("1.03.03", $selected_items_array) ? 'found' : 'not found';
```

So, 
`item_no` => `1.03.03` is exist in this multi dimensional array so it returns true otherwise it returns false, 
But I want to get the values of `price`,`sor_id` of 1st position.
But it returns only `1` or '0' so how to return whole array or array `index` so using that array or index I can fetch values. Or any other options.

Comment: Where's the data coming from? If its a database you're probably better off with queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there. Instead of true, return the id of the matching element:

```
function in_array_r($needle, $haystack, $strict = false) {
    foreach ($haystack as $key => $item) {
        if (($strict ? $item === $needle : $item == $needle) || (is_array($item) && in_array_r($needle, $item, $strict))) {
            return $key;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

$matching_item = in_array_r("1.03.03", $selected_items_array);
echo $matching_item===false ? "not found" : " found at item ".$matching_item;
```

Comment: Oh. Thank you so much. Great that's perfectly working. If It's possible I will give you 100 upvotes. I was stuck in it since 3 hour ;)